# Getting weird margin trying to stack to svgs one on top of eachother in smaller aspect ratios

Tags: html, css

I have two svgs that act as spacers in between sections, when the page is at pc/notebook aspect ratio they look like one big svg, but when shrinking into tablet/ phone mode they get a weird margin between them that separates the two svgs.

Svgs in desktop aspect ratio:

[image]

Svgs in mobile aspect ratio:

[image]

Here is the html:

```
 <div className="small-spacer layer1Top"></div>
 <div className="small-spacer layer1Bot"></div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.layer1Top {
    background-image: url("../images/layer1Top.svg");
}

.layer1Bot {
    background-image: url("../images/layer1Bot.svg");
}

.small-spacer {
    aspect-ratio: 960/100;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I tried adding a parent div to the two divs with `display: inline-block` but the only thing it did is making the margin bigger.

Comment: I have encountered this issue before so here is my weird question. Is this browser opened on an extended monitor? If so try to pull this browser on your laptop screen. Sometimes dev tools mobile responsive feature doesnt react well on extended monitors.

Comment: as a side-question: why do you need to create 2 elements instead of adding both svg to the same element?

Comment: @KvnG. it might be dev tools being bugged, because i had this same svg without touching anything to the code for a couple of days and that line didn't appear and today out of nowhere it appeared.

Comment: @tacoshy i made the svgs in Haikei app and it doesn't have the option to make this svg so i made one svg and then inverted it to look like this.

Comment: you mis-understand my question. you can add multiple background-images to a single element. so no reason to use 2 elements

Comment: @tacoshy I didn't know that could be done, what is the syntax for that?

Comment: just devide multiple images with a comma. Works the same then with position and size property: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

Comment: I'd be more comfortable with the top one's CSS having `background-position: bottom center` and the bottom one having `background-position: top center`.

Comment: Why not just have two SVG's inside *one* div? Why the preference for using SVG in a background-image context? It might solve your problem to put a column-flexbox around two inline-SVGs. Unless you're using them a *lot* then I guess you are saving a small amount of bandwidth not having them inline.

Answer (score -2):

***ANSWER***

— ***ERROR -***
Why are you using className property on the HTML div element here below?

```
 <div className = "small-spacer layer1Top"></div>
 <div className = "small-spacer layer1Bot"></div>
```

The className property sets or returns an element's class attribute. HTMLElementObject.className = class

So, it should be:-

```
 <div class = "small-spacer layer1Top"></div>
 <div class = "small-spacer layer1Bot"></div>
```

— Now, to stack two svgs on top of each other I have used z-index.

***z-index*** only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky) and flex items (elements that are direct children of display:flex elements).

***Note :*** If two positioned elements overlap without a z-index specified, the element positioned last in the HTML code will be shown on top.

***Note :*** Both images are of the same size in pixels. Dimensions: 1920 x 328

```css
.image1 {
    position: relative;
    width : 100% !important;
}

.image2 {
    z-index: 1;
    width : 100% !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<img class = "image1" src = "img/vibration1.png" />
<img class = "image2" src = "img/vibration1.png" />
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Reason why it was written as className because its probably coded in React